# send email using REST API using Powershell

Tags: rest, email, powershell, office365

Is it possible to send an email using the REST API by Powershell?

I have tried using the [this reference](https://sites.utexas.edu/glenmark/2014/04/30/exchange-online-mailbox-access-from-powershell-via-rest/) but I'm running into problems:

Also this uses a legacy API (I'm using V1.0)

I can read email (for myself and delegates) which occurs quickly and conveniently. Its just a single line based on `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users`

This is what I have so far but its not working..As if its no surprise I'm getting the usual Invoke-RestMethod :

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

```
$uri = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/sendmail"


$UserName = "andrew.stevens@my.domain"
$Password = cat C:\MydomainCreds.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,$password


$body = "{
 ""Subject"": ""This is a send test"",
 ""Importance"": ""High"",
 ""Body"": {
 ""ContentType"": ""HTML"",
 ""Content"": ""How about this for a surprise!""
 },
 ""ToRecipients"": [
 {
  ""Address"": ""mytestmailbox@anywhere.com""
 }
 ]
 }"



Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Credential $cred -ContentType "application/json" -Body $Body
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON data which represents for message is malformed. The root element for the message should be **Message**. The **Recipient** is also incorrect, it should be contain the **EmailAddress** property which is **EmailAddress** type.

Here is a sample should work for your reference:

```
$body = "{
""Message"":{
 ""Subject"": ""This is a send test"",
 ""Importance"": ""High"",
 ""Body"": {
 ""ContentType"": ""HTML"",
 ""Content"": ""How about this for a surprise!""
 },
 ""ToRecipients"": [
 {
 ""EmailAddress"":{
  ""Address"": ""mytestmailbox@anywhere.com""
  }
 }
 ]
 }}"
```

Refer to links below for more about Office 365 REST API:

[Outlook Mail REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#Createandsendmessages)

[Resource reference for the Mail, Calendar, Contacts, and Task REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#Recipient)

Comment: You are one clever guy!